# MySQL master to slave dump fails when done over SSH pipe

Tags: mysql, replication, mysqldump

When we need to [re]build a MySQL-5.5 slave, our usual approach is this (`CHANGE MASTER TO` / `START SLAVE` omitted for clarity):

```shell
master$ mysqldump -uroot -p --all-databases --master-data > dump.sql
master$ scp dump.sql slave:
slave$ mysql -uroot -p < dump.sql
```

This has always worked flawlessly, and we are used to doing it on busy masters without any problem. Now we're trying to automate it a little more and I came out trying to run this from the slave system:

```shell
ssh masterhost.mydomain "mysqldump -uroot -p --all-databases --master-data" \|
  mysql -uroot -p
```

We're basically doing the same thing we do with a dump file, but we're doing it "on the fly" over SSH. At first it seems to work, after asking for passwords it runs `mysqldump` on the master system, its output goes through `ssh` and gets piped in `mysql` on the slave system. But then when we `START SLAVE` we almost always get duplicate primary key conflicts on the slave system (note that IO thread is running without problems).

As far as I know `--master-data` should acquire enough locking (`--lock-all-tables` implied, and we also tried adding it explicitly) to avoid this kind of problems, and it takes care of sending out correct log positions from the master so we cannot get them wrong.

I should mention that we have a mix of InnoDB and MyISAM tables.

Why doesn't this dump-and-restore-over-SSH work just like the dump-to-file-restore-from-file, as I would expect?